# Windbg !name2ee mscorlib.dll Exception

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

I use windbg to debug .Net 4.0 on window 10 64bit

```
.loadby sos clr
!name2ee mscorlib.dll
```

> c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.name2ee debugger extension.
>         PC: 571ebff3  VA: 00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 00000000

How to fix this exception ?

Comment: which Debugging Tools version do you use? Try the latest version 10586.202: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: The cause and workaround is given here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/46723fca-8d7c-4d61-b447-14e3bef01df8/windbg-access-violation-exception-0xc0000005-when-running-the-clrstack-command?forum=windbg  It is fixed in CoreCLR. Unknown when full framework will get the fix.